# Failed building wheel for cryptography. Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, git, scrapy

I couldn't install Scrapy on my system after I upgraded pip to 20.0.2.
And what file do I have to install manually in order to make it work?
Please help me out.

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#ubuntu-14-04-or-above

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install python3 python3-dev python3-pip libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev